# get value part of specific word

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

want to search sting and need part of string

`example.txt`:

CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE ,NO FALLBACK , NO BEFORE JOURNAL, NO AFTER JOURNAL, CHECKSUM = DEFAULT, DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKADSRATIO

its should find `$$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE` and i need only `TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE` or after `$$ENV$$_` in what ever string is there need that string, i don't want to print next string